# How to get the interval value from two UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I have two UIDatePickers. `startDatePicker` is to choose a start date and `endDatePicker` is to choose an end date. It should be something like

START: 2015/06/25 11:00
END: 2015/07/06 13:00
->Time Interval: 12 days 2 hours = 1044000 seconds

And the 1044000 seconds is what I want to get here. Just I am not sure how.

I am guessing maybe I can use
`startDatePicker.date.timeIntervalSinceDate(endDatePicker.date)`
to get the value? If so, what is the necessary settings for the two UIDatePickers?

Or maybe there are other ways to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your question? You seem to know the code to use to get the interval.

Comment: You are doing it just right. use the value

Comment: @rmaddy I want to know how to set up `startDatePicker` and `endDatePicker` properly for that code since I only found the code but no further instruction for using it.

Comment: Read the docs for `UIDatePicker datePickerMode`. Is that what you are asking about?